Sum of Repetends of Prime Reciprocals
Just a recreational mathematician here with a random question. All reciprocals of primes are periodic and there is some rational number that approximates them exactly up to their period. For example, $0.142857$ approximates $\tfrac{1}{7}$ exactly up to the point at which it repeats).
What would the sum of these rational numbers look like? I assume it would be some sort of telescoping series which is built of the series of $\tfrac{1}{p}$, but I do not have the mathematical knowledge to formalize the relationship in a way which would help me determine if the series converges to a value or diverges. I believe the series looks like:
$$S=\frac 12+\frac 3{10}+\frac 15 + \sum_{p=7,11,13,17\dots}^\infty \left(\frac 1p - \frac 1{p\times10^{k}}\right)$$
where $k$ is the smallest positive integer satisfying $10^k\equiv 1\pmod p$ as this should provide the given expansion:
$$
\begin{align}
S&=\frac 12+\frac 3{10}+\frac 15+\left(\frac 17-\frac 1{7000000}\right)+\left(\frac 1{11}-\frac 1{1100}\right) + \dots\\&=0.5+0.3+0.2+0.142857+0.09 + \dots
\end{align}
$$
I apologize if my question is unclear, or if my post is wrongly formatted (first time poster), again I am not really a professional mathematician, I just like doing little puzzles like this for fun. If this is a known proof then I would love to be informed of that! Thanks for taking the time of day to check out this question!

Great question, your observations about the terms in the series are correct! Are you familiar with the fact that $\sum \frac{1}{p}$ diverges? You can then use the comparison test to prove that your series also diverges (Hint: all but finitely many terms of your series are at least $\tfrac{1}{2p}$).

Ah that makes sense! Thank you for the answer there! I feel like I should have thought to do that but I was kind of hoping it would result in some nice finite number. I guess by limit comparison as well its somewhat obvious that this series will behave like 1/p. Thank you for the answer!
